# Socket.io emitting and broadcasting events but wont "hear" events from the server

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, pug

I'm new to Socket.io and Express. I'm just working on getting the basic chat scenario up and running while assigning users to a session. From my research I've realized there are about as many ways to do this as there are stars. I've also realized that there really isnt one "accepted standard" (if I'm wrong, do show me). This was the simplest manner I figured out (using req.session.'name' = 'value')

Heres my server code:

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , path = require('path')
  , http = require('http')
  , io = require('socket.io')
  , cookie = require("cookie")
  , connect = require("connect")
  , app = express();


// all environments
app.configure(function() {
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());

  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({secret: 'secret'}));
    app.use(app.router);
});

var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('ready');
});

var io = io.listen(server);


app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/user', routes.user);  

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.emit('connected', { connect: 'CONNECTED TO THE SERVER' });

    socket.on('client connect', function (data) {
        console.log("HEARD THE CLIENT");
    });

    socket.on('addingNewUser', function (data) {
      console.log('BROADCASTING ADDUSER');
      console.log(data);
      socket.broadcast.emit('addUser', data);
    });
});
```

Heres my index.jade code:

```
extends layout

block content
  script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")
  script(src="/javascripts/index.js")
  script.
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

    socket.on('connected', function (data) {
      socket.emit('client connect', { connect: 'CLIENT IS CONNECTED' });
    });

    socket.on('addUser', function (data) {
      console.log("ADDING NEW USER:");
      req.session.user = data;
      console.log(data);
      $("#usernames").append('<p>'+data+'</p>');
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#submit').click( function (data) {
          console.log("SUBMITTING FORM!");
          var userName = $("#add_user").val();
          console.log("user name " + userName);
          socket.emit('addingNewUser', { user: userName });
          return false;
        });
    });    


  #users.large-3.columns
    h5 Online Users
    p#usernames

  #messages.large-6.columns
    form
      fieldset
        legend I am (the) Legend
        input(type='text', id='add_user', name='add_user', placeholder='Type your name.')
        input.button.small(type='submit', id="submit", value='Send')
    #show_messages
      ul#user_message
  .large-3.columns
```

Some of the indentation might be off due to the StackOverflow formatting but in the actual file its good.

You can track all the console logs pretty well. It stops at the console.log after "BROADCASTING USER".

For some reason the listener for 'addUser' isnt picking up anything.

Any ideas?

---

Edit:
As pointed out in the comments, broadcast only emits to the sockets it did not originate from. So thats why it was never triggering the listener.

However, now I have a new problem. One that I've come across before.

In the listener for 'addUser' it returns an error for 'req.session.user' saying that 'Uncaught ReferenceError: req is not defined'.

How do I overcome this?

Comment: Do you have two clients up and running?  From [the documentation](http://socket.io/#how-to-use) `Broadcasting means sending a message to everyone else except for the socket that starts it.`

Comment: Good catch. I didnt know that. I opened up a second client and now I have a new problem that I've come across before. I'll post it as an edit.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up your client and server logic.

This code (from your template):

```
socket.on('addUser', function (data) {
  console.log("ADDING NEW USER:");
  req.session.user = data;
  console.log(data);
  $("#usernames").append('<p>'+data+'</p>');
});
```

Is executing on the client side where there is not req object available.

By default, socket.io and express sessions don't play together - you need to add some additional logic to your app.

There are several projects that aim to make this easier such as:

- [express.io](https://github.com/techpines/express.io)
- [session.socket.io](https://github.com/wcamarao/session.socket.io)

Comment: Gotcha. Moved it over to my server side to just happen when `addingNewUser` is triggered but it still says it is not defined: 

`socket.on('addingNewUser', function (data) {
      console.log('BROADCASTING ADDUSER');
      console.log(data);
      req.session.user = data;
       socket.broadcast.emit('addUser', data);
   });`

How do I get around this? Can I pass the 'req' object inside of the socket?

(sorry, I cant get it to format block code inside of comments)